# Nodejs automatically shuts after running for some time

Tags: node.js

My environment is ubuntu 16.04 with npm 5.0.0 and node 8.0.0 installed. I created an express application and started it with nohup npm start & in the application root directory. However, a couple of minutes later the app became unreachable and the process was lost. I tried restarting several time but the process always automatically exits. How can I start a long-running nodejs app?

Comment: When you say "after a couple of minutes later" what do you mean? If you are doing this on a machine that you are not actively watching, to keep the process running you may need to use something like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: use nodemon will be best or pm2

Comment: Looks like your application is crashing. Nohup produces a log from the application output, have you looked into it? Nohup should work but for leaving an application running people normally resort to forever or pm2.

Comment: The log did not contain any error info. It just automatically shuts down

Comment: Check if server session is getting timeout. go to pm2 logs full path and error.log and out.log

Answer (score 0):

Use pm2 daemon for setting Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 16.04

Follow commands

sudo npm install -g pm2

pm2 start server.js   //Yor main node server.js

pm2 stop server   //no need of giving .js , .js only required at start of process

pm2 restart server  //for any changes are done to restart

For more You can follow digital ocean tutorials for more details from below link

[Digital_Ocean_Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Tried with PM2. Always got errored status after running pm2 start app.js :(